# "The compressed (zip) folder is invalid or corrupted" error after downloading zip file - sometimes, but not always

Tags: zip

I have a zip archive of ~250Mb located on an Apache HTTP server. Several users have complained of a "corrupt zip folder" after downloading the file directly from the website (albeit the site is built on Drupal but it is using the public download method so it should be a direct download)

The error message when they try to open it in Windows is:

> The compressed (zip) folder is invalid or corrupted

I have tried this myself on Windows XP and using both Firefox 14 and IE8. Sometimes it downloads and opens correctly, sometimes I get the error.

Another user is on Windows 7 and using Internet Explorer and has got this message after several download attempts.

When I download via FTP using Filezilla I can open the zip file without errors.

As FTP and HTTP download works at times, then I assume the file on the server is not corrupted but something happens during download and re-uploading the file would not fix anything (and I have tried this).

I created the zip file using IZArc but I am not so sure the method of creation is relevant in this case as it sometimes works.

1. What causes the above error messages?
2. Why does it happen some of the time and not all of the time?
3. What could I do to ensure zip files open without any errors in future?

Comment: The answer to all your questions is that the file is corrupt.  Do they get this error when using actual software design to extract a .zip file?

Comment: Check to make sure that either clients are getting a `Content-Length` header when they download the file or the transfer encoding is chunked. Otherwise, truncation is possible.

Comment: @Ramhound, that's more the question really than the answer. The question is: What causes the corruption in cases where it is corrupt sometimes and not others (and for different people on different network connections/software set-ups). Why should it be so inconsistent assuming the original file is OK?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, that sounds promising. Can you clarify how one would go about checking that clients are getting a `Content-Length` header? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I used [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to check the response headers and the `Content-Length` header is sent with value that is the size of the file so it looks like all is well there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What causes the above error messages?

The download is probably corrupted or truncated (incomplete). Check if the downloaded filesize is same as the size on the server.

> Why does it happen some of the time and not all of the time?

The download could be truncated due to the connection being dropped, which is something random - it might happen and might not happen. If your connection quality is better, it'll probably be less likely to occur.

> What could I do to ensure zip files open without any errors in future?

Provide checksums for all your downloads, and get your users to verify them. You can't really avoid network issues, however. You may wish to speak to your host.

Comment: That is probably the most helpful and complete answer, thanks. I will look into what you say and most likely come back and mark this as the answer. In the meantime, why do you think it would be so inconsistent given different users on different connections and software set-ups? Assuming the original file is OK (which it must be if it sometimes opens) I don't see why I should particularly be having this problem as often as I do with this file. I have downloaded a lot of zips in my life and only occasionally have corrupt files, but not as often as in this instance. Thanks.

Comment: Particularly, what could I ask my host in order to point them in the right direction to a possible solution to the problem? What might be going wrong at their end? Thanks.

Comment: Is it only with a particular zipfile? Have you tested with zipfiles (or other files) of smaller or larger sizes? It could be large size providing more time for a connection drop, which is why you only see this problem with this file. Also, could it be the PHP script serving the download getting timed out (since you mentioned Drupal)? If not, you might ask your host to check for any connection problems on their end, mentioning this problem.

Comment: I haven't tested with others but will try. It makes sense that larger files can have more connection drop issues. I and most users are on stable broadband Net connections though (doesn't TCP/IP handle this problem?). I am linking directly to the file so I assume Drupal doesn't get involved in that (although it can if you change to private download method). In this case, the users are non-technical and wouldn't cope with checking checksums. I have re-created the zip using Windows rather than 3rd party software to see if that makes a difference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The host isn't providing any help other than saying that they can download the file OK at their end so while I don't think I know exactly why this has been happening so frequently I am going to mark this as the answer as it will probably apply in most cases. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, they might have no issues because they might be testing it on a local area network..

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to troubleshoot what's going on is to use MD5 or SHA-1 hashes of that zip file.  I assume you have the original zip available to you offline.

Using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you can compute a SHA-1 or MD5 hash of your zip file then publish the result.  Hashes are really cool because they can be used to verify to the bit level that one file is exactly the same as another.  For example:
The hash for a file containing "0123456789" is 3749f52bb326ae96782b42dc0a97b4c1.
The hash for a file containing "1123456789" is b0b7fa225796be83e7fea1345c13d3dd.

If I remember my ASCII right, there's only a single bit difference between the two strings but as you can see there's a huge difference in the resulting hashes.  Publishing an MD5 or SHA-1 hash is a very common thing to do in the software development world since it's a very good way to ensure that you're files aren't corrupted.  After publishing the MD5/SHA-1 hash, you could have your customers take a hash of the zip to see if it's actually corrupted or not.

There are plenty of utilities out there for Windows, Linux and Mac that will generate MD5 and SHA-1 hashes.  I use Cygwin because it's free.

Comment: This makes sense in many situations. I am dealing with very non-technical users, though, who would not cope with hash checking, but that's good advice generally. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when one of the file names in your folders has a special character, such as quotation marks `"`. You have to ignore those files.

But it is difficult when you have several thousand files, maybe you can try [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Welcome on SU. If you ignore some file you will miss some content. I understand that probably mean to suggest  to _avoid_ the use of such kind of names.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, *user110346* is onto something.

I had the same issue - created a .zip on a Mac that resulted in an error on Windows 7 (but extracted properly on the Mac).

Following his hint, I noticed that I have a bunch of folders with a bullet in the name (option-8 on the Mac keyboard).  Removed all those folders, re-zipped and presto - the .zip file works without issue on Windows.

So, apparently, using characters that are illegal in Windows in the filenames contained in the zip-file will cause Windows to report the "*the compressed (zipped) file XYZXYZ is invalid*" error with opening the .zip file.

Comment: The bullet character is illegal I guess...weird.  You can also install 7zip and use its "test" option to test if the zip file is bad or not...

Answer (score 0):

If file on client side have correct size, this situation might be caused by faulty memory on client PC or faulty network equipment in between. Often random bit-switching is not especially apparent in many applications, but when it comes to checksums that are used to check archive integrity, every bit matter and those errors become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows XP.  I was getting that same message and was unable to open a zip file until I downloaded winzip185 off the internet.  Then, from inside winzip, I was able to easily open the file and drag and drop it onto my desktop.  Hope that helps!

Comment: 7zip also extracted something for me that yielded the OP's error message with the normal extractor.  Weird.